# Найти найменший (по модулю) элемент матрицы

Tags: excel, vba

Есть матрица в Excel. Как записать код на `Visual Basic` (функцию) чтобы найти найменший по модулю елемент матрицы?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если речь идет о алгоритме - просмотреть в интернете  поиск минимума в массиве, с той лишь разницей, что вам нужно запоминать на 1, а 2 индекса элемента

Comment: Нужно найти минимальное значение или адрес ячейки с ним? если второе - что делать, если ячеек с таким значением несколько?

Comment: Если надо просто минимальное значение, то вообще `MinValue = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A1:E10"))`, и никаких функций не надо.

Comment: Мне нужно написать на Visual Basic функцию и ее визивать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Dim MinValue as single
   Dim i as integer, j as integer

   MinValue = Cells(i,j).Value

   for i=1 to RowNum
      for j=1 to ColNum
         if Cells(i.j).Value < MinValue then MinValue = Cells(i,j).Value
      next
   next
```

Обратите внимание на начальные позиции матрицы (координаты верхнего левого угла). 1,1 - это если матрица в самом начале страницы, вверху слева, позиция А1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_()
    Dim rRng As Range, c_ As Range
    Dim dMin As Double
    
    Set rRng = Range("G87:L96")
    dMin = Abs(rRng(1, 1).Value)
    
    For Each c_ In rRng
        If dMin > Abs(c_.Value) Then dMin = Abs(c_.Value)
    Next c_
    
    Set rRng = Nothing
    MsgBox "Наименьшее значение в диапазоне " & dMin, 64, ""
End Sub
```